# How can I extract values from a dataframe or filter based on some criteria in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame with extracted values from some files. How can I filter or extract the first two rows of data after the value u in col 1. The col 1 value will have a range of 80 that I want to capture after the value u. The value u might be two or three files after a new filex in col 0 or none at all as shown below in file3.

```
    0          1          2       3
0   file1   value u     file1   value u
1   file1   value u     file1   value u
2   file1   value 85    file1   th_v 5
3   file1   value 10    file1   th_v 2
4   file1   value 10    file1   th_v 4
5   file1   value 88    file1   th_v 4
6   file2   value u     file2   value u
7   file2   value 88    file2   th_v 7
8   file2   value 2     file2   th_v 4
9   file2   value 88    file2   th_v 3
10  file2   value 0     file2   th_v 1
11  file3   value 89    file3   th_v 5
12  file3   value 2     file3   th_v 5
13  file3   value 4     file3   th_v 1

output:
         0          1         2       3
    0   file1   value 85    file1   th_v 5
    1   file1   value 10    file1   th_v 2
    2   file2   value 88    file2   th_v 7
    3   file2   value 2     file2   th_v 4
    4   file3   value 89    file3   th_v 5
    5   file3   value 2     file3   th_v 5
```

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'll second what @Tserenjamts said.

Comment: So I Ive tried splitting the list and doing a range to capture the second value but no luck. Also tried to place in a dataframe to filter on value like if/else conditions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that explanation. What is the format of the data before it's put into the DataFrame?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile its a list.

Comment: Can you share what it looks like?

Comment: @s_col The thing you just added? That’s a tuple, is it a tuple in your program?

Comment: @AlexanderCecile sorry your correct. I changed it to reflect a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If same pattern of data (same groups of file columns and same ends of values columns) for pairs of columns is possible test if last value is numeric and then [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df = df[df[1].str.contains('\d$')].groupby(0).head(2)
```